# "RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned" in Numpy

Tags: python, excel, numpy, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

everyone. I will be concise on the subject.
It happens that I have been imitating the LINEST function (from excel, that is, linear estimation) in Python. When it comes to several values, the coefficients come out as indicated by the excel.
But when I use 3 values ​​on both "X" and "Y" axis (below code):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([18.4,23.3,28.2])
y = np.array([0.32,0.30,0.10])
z = np.polyfit(x,y,3)
print(f"The value of the coefficient A is {z[0]}")
print(f"The value of coefficient B is {z[1]}")
print(f"The value of coefficient C is {z[2]}")
print(f"The value of the coefficient D is {z[3]}")
print(f"And the resulting equation is: PC = P3({z[0]})+ P2({z[1]}) + P({z[2]}) + ({z[3]}) + P")
```

The resulting values ​​are:

```
The value of the coefficient A is -6.88767034112518e-05
The value of coefficient B is 0.0010660434176759947
The value of the coefficient C is 0.041704547338169494
The value of the coefficient D is -0.3792156311034974
```

Along with the error:

```
/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3398: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
```

But they do not match those reported in excel using that function:

A:-9,487E-05 B:2,883E-03 C:0,000E+00 D:-6,500329E-02

As I repeat, when there were more than 8 data (both on the X and Y axis, the coefficients coincided perfectly)
I don't know if you could help me with my 2 problems, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. LINEST produces a simple linear regression, and its results on the 3 data points in your example can be matched with `np.polyfit(x,y,1)`. What are the A, B, C and D values you are showing from Excel, and why are you trying to fit a 3rd degree polynomial to the data?  The warning probably comes from the fact that you are trying to estimate 4 polynomial coefficients (degrees 0-3) from just 3 data points.

Comment: Good afternoon first. I just wanted to mimic the LINEAR function in python. In any case, how would you do linear regression to get the same excel result? Is that, as I said, use this formula for a large set of values and the coefficients did coincide.

Comment: Okay, it was not obvious from your post, but your Excel results (coefficients A through D) come from `=LINEST(y1:y3,x1:x3^{1,2,3})`, where `{1,2,3}` define a 3rd degree polynomial. You need `n+1` data points to uniquely describe a polynomial of degree `n`, which is not the case in your example. Excel nullifies one of the coefficients (sets it to 0) as a result, while NumPy computes a full set of coefficients but warns you that the best fit is not well-defined.  More info on the warning can be found in [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

Comment: In that case, what library or code do you recommend so that the result is as close as possible to that of excel?